# PHP : Concat one element array to another element array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in php like this :

```
[
    'gudang' => 'A'
    'blok' => '2'
    0 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1C519081726A'
        'urut' => '28204'
        'lokasi_terakhir' => '411'
    ]
    1 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1A518081712A'
        'urut' => '28205'
        'lokasi_terakhir' => '211'
    ]
    2 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1A420081707A'
        'urut' => '28206'
        'lokasi_terakhir' => '311'
    ]
]
```

I need concat element `gudang` , `barang`, to another element that have element `lokasi_terakhir` which is array tipe. I need like this :

```
[
    0 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1C519081726A'
        'urut' => '28204'
        'lokasi_terakhir' => 'A2411'
    ]
    1 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1A518081712A'
        'urut' => '28205'
        'lokasi_terakhir' => 'A2211'
    ]
    2 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1A420081707A'
        'urut' => '28206'
        'lokasi_terakhir' => 'A2311'
    ]
]
```

I need to remove `gudang` , `blok`, then concat to each `lokasi_terakhir` element.
Please advise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the question is unclear, voting to close

Answer (score 1):

Try using `array_map`:

```php
$input = [
    0 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1C519081726A'
        'urut' => '28204'
        'lokasi_terakhir' => '411'
    ]
    1 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1A518081712A'
        'urut' => '28205'
        'lokasi_terakhir' => '211'
    ]
    2 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1A420081707A'
        'urut' => '28206'
        'lokasi_terakhir' => '311'
    ]
];

$gudang = 'A';
$blok = 2;

$output = array_map(function(&$value) use ($gudang, $blok) {
    $value['lokasi_terakhir'] = $gudang.$blok.$value['lokasi_terakhir'];
}, $input);
```

Comment: PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Illegal string offset 'lokasi_terakhir''

Comment: Remove 'gudang' and 'blok' from your input array.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$gudang = $array['gudang'];
$blok = $array['blok'];
foreach($array as $key =>$val){
   $array['lokasi_terakhir'] = $gudang.$blok.$val['lokasi_terakhir'];
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new_arr = [];
$str = $arr['gudang'] . $arr['blok'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr)-2; $i++) {
    $new_arr[$i] = $arr[$i];
    $new_arr[$i]['lokasi_terakhir'] = $str.$arr[$i]['lokasi_terakhir'];
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = [
    'gudang' => 'A',
    'blok' => '2',
    0 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1C519081726A',
        'urut' => '28204',
        'lokasi_terakhir' => '411'
    ],
    1 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1A518081712A',
        'urut' => '28205',
        'lokasi_terakhir' => '211'
    ],
    2 => [
        'coil_no' => 'DNA07X1A420081707A',
        'urut' => '28206',
        'lokasi_terakhir' => '311'
    ]
];
$length = count($array1);
$array2 = array_splice($array1, 2, $length);
echo json_encode($array2);
```